# Python. Передача значений из списка

Tags: python

Всем привет Есть данные которые приходят из базы.

```
Record = [("id1,),('id2',),('id3')]
```

Есть рабочий Post запрос к серверу, он принимает данные

```
"Param1" = Record,
"Param2" = 700,
"Param3" = "id_number"
```

Как реализовать так, чтобы Param1 принимал данные поочередно из переменной Record и направлял отдельный Post запрос на каждое значение?

```
"Param1" = "id1"
"Param2" = 700,
"Param3" = "id_number"

"Param1" = "id2",
"Param2" = 700,
"Param3" = "id_number"

"Param1" = "id3",
"Param2" = 700,
"Param3" = "id_number"
```

Comment: а документация на API сервера у вас есть?

Comment: Через цикл пройдись по списку, чтото такое:
for id_item in Record:
    Param1 = id_item

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Amgarak Вернее даже там `id_item[0]` надо будет брать - там кортежи внутри.

Comment: @Amgarak `("id1")` - это не кортеж, это просто строка в скобках. Для кортежа нужна запятая: `("id1",)`

Comment: @insolor точно,  спасибо за правку

Answer (score 0):

```
Record = [('id1',),('id2',),('id3',)]

for i in Record:
    body = {
        "Param1": i[0],
        "Param2": 700,
        "Param3": "id_number"
    }
```

если `id_number` это цифра в id, то:

```
Record = [('id1',),('id2',),('id3',)]

for i in Record:
    body = {
        "Param1": i[0],
        "Param2": 700,
        "Param3": i[0][2]
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, с этим циклом все работает отлично, только в Param1 передается переменная i без скобок.